# Zend pass variable to view

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend, before used laravel and other frameworks. So i got one Zend project to modify, the problem is that i can't pass variables from controller to view.

Controller:

```
$temp_id = $this->_request->getParam ('temp_id');

if($temp_id){
    $data = $card_temp_model->getSingle('*', 'id='.(int)$temp_id);

    if(!$data['icon_id'])
        $data['icon_id'] = 9;
    if(!$data['icon2x_id'])
        $data['icon2x_id'] = 10;
    $data['template_only']=1;

    $form->setDefaults($data);
}

$locations = $card_location_model->getAll('*', 'card_id='.(int)$temp_id);

$this->view->locations = $locations;
$this->view->form = $form;
```

And my view file:

```
<?=
    die(print_r($this->locations));
?>
```

I can't get locations in my view file. Someone maybe can explain me why?

Comment: The assignation is okay, what controller and what action you use? Are you sure you have your view in proper directory?

Comment: does the view show up with out the values in place?

Comment: Controller: Pass_IndexController, action: formAction, and view is /applications/modules/pass/views/scripts/index kinda sure but not 100% sure, first time using zend, so maybe i'm doing something wrong in some wrong place ;) yes view shows up w/o values. If i dump $this, i can see that locations array is somewhere, but array is so big, that i can't navigate trough it to find where exactly is my location array

Comment: well, which version of ZF are you using . ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign the variable to view in ZF you should use this code

```
$this->view->var = "some text"; // where "some text" may be variable or everthing else.
```

Your problem is rather in placing your files. ZF directory structure can be changed so if you use directory structure.

```
APPLICATION
  controllers
     NameController.php
Views
  Name
     Index.html
```

then in Index.html just `echo $var`;

in NameController.php create IndexAction() method and assign variable to view.

To show this controler use `domain.com/name/` or `domain.com/name/index`

That's all to make it works.

Comment: domain.com/en/pass/index/form/temp_id/170 so controller is pass, an action is index. So it looks like i'm in right controller, and i'm using right view.

Comment: what is en? It's controller? What's pass is it action/module? Are you using your own routing?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller ...

```
$this->view->foo = 'sample string or content';
```

In the view use the escape method to prevent xss issues.

```
echo $this->escape($this->foo);
```